# VSCode - Bracket Pair Colorization in HTML/CSS (How to?)

Tags: visual-studio-code, brackets

I'm using native VSCode Bracket Pair Colorization and just realized it doesn't work with HTML, and specially CSS (which I'm more interested in). I tried looking in Settings and searching Google for some help, but didn't find any help. Does any of you guys know some .json setting, so I can add HTML/CSS to this feature?

Comment: It doesn't look like HTML is currently supported https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/137504

I assume CSS would be supported.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this on Github and it's work. You can try it

```
"editor.language.colorizedBracketPairs": [
    ["[", "]"],
    ["(", ")"],
    ["{", "}"],
    ["<", "</"],
    ["<", "/>"]
],
```

Comment: a link to the source would have been nice :/ also related: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_62#_customizable-bracket-pairs

Answer (score 0):

Bracket pair colorization is by default supported in CSS/SCSS. As for HTML, it does not have any brackets, but it still highlights the ending tag if you click on the start tag.

[image]

Comment: For me it doesn't work on css ([Imgur Image](https://i.imgur.com/x58CoMS.png)). Could it be some conflict with my theme (Dracula Official) or something else?

Comment: Everything seems fine to me. CSS in general has only one level. Try writing some CSS code inside a media query. This should colorize the inner braces of media query.

Edit: I am using "Github Theme"

Comment: I installed the Bracket Pair Colorizer 2 plugin and is working fine now. I know that brackets with different colors on css isn't important, but for me I really like the feeling.

Answer (score 0):

> As for HTML, it does not have any brackets

- Well, it does if you are using Angular's interpolation.

Til now, 2022 Nov. 3, vscode's implementation still doesn't work with html. So i disabled the native and reinstalled Bracket Pair Colorizer 2. Now it's working.

Though already deprecated, but everything works. I will not settle with the latest and greatest but lacks in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need opening and closing tags to be colored. What you need is the **Indent Guides to be colored**, and you can achieve this without any extension.

[Image after running first code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvVam.png)

1. Hit **Ctrl+P** in VS Code.
2. Write **>settings.json** and hit Enter.
3. Paste the following code:

.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
"editorIndentGuide.activeBackground1": "#2bff00" },
```

**Change the color of indent guide:**
You can also change the color of indent guide to whatever you like by simply modifying the hex value to your desired color or by hovering over the color and selecting the one you prefer.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground1": "#ffcb61"
},
```

[Image after running second code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2GOt.png)

*Also this works with every other programming language.*